# Programmatically setting itemcommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a grid that i have been trying to set up in the code behind. So far everything has been going smoothly and working, but when
i go to set the itemcommand event or any event for the matter, when i go to click on the command or do something that should cause to trigger the event, nothing ends up firing. So i was wondering what exactly i am doing wrong with my declaration on my item command.
You will find my code below:

```
private void createRadGrid()
    {
        //create radgrid
        RadGrid rg = new RadGrid();
        rg.ID = "RadGridView";

        //setting the datasource and itemcommand event handler.
        rg.DataSourceID = "MachineDataSet";
        rg.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(RadGridView_ItemCommand);

        rg.Width = 862;
        rg.CellSpacing = 2;
        rg.CellPadding = 4;
        rg.BorderWidth = 3;
        rg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        rg.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        rg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        rg.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        rg.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        rg.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;
        rg.ShowStatusBar = true;

        rg.AllowPaging = true;
        rg.PageSize = 5;
        rg.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
        rg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        rg.MasterTableView.PageSize = 5;
        rg.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
        rg.MasterTableView.ClientDataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
        rg.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        rg.ClientSettings.Resizing.AllowColumnResize = true;
        rg.ClientSettings.Resizing.EnableRealTimeResize = true;
        rg.ClientSettings.Resizing.ResizeGridOnColumnResize = true;

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn.DataField = "ID";
        boundColumn.HeaderText = "ID";
        boundColumn.UniqueName = "MachineID";
        boundColumn.Visible = false;
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn1 = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn1.DataField = "SiteName";
        boundColumn1.HeaderText ="Site Name";
        boundColumn1.Resizable = true;
        boundColumn1.ReadOnly = true;
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn1);

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn2 = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn2.DataField = "Name";
        boundColumn2.HeaderText = "Machine Name";
        boundColumn2.Resizable = true;
        boundColumn2.ReadOnly = true;
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn2);

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn3 = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn3.DataField = "MachineType";
        boundColumn3.HeaderText = "Machine Type";
        boundColumn3.Resizable = true;
        boundColumn3.ReadOnly = true;
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn3);

        GridBoundColumn boundColumn4 = new GridBoundColumn();
        boundColumn4.DataField = "MachineModel";
        boundColumn4.HeaderText = "Machine Model";
        boundColumn4.Resizable = true;
        boundColumn4.ReadOnly = true;
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn4);

        GridButtonColumn buttonColumn = new GridButtonColumn();
        buttonColumn.ButtonType = GridButtonColumnType.PushButton;
        buttonColumn.CommandName = "AssignNewValues";
        buttonColumn.Resizable = true;
        buttonColumn.Text = "Assign New Values";
        rg.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);

        PlaceHolder_RadGridView.Controls.Add(rg);
    }
```

The problem area seems to be in this line

```
rg.ItemCommand += new GridCommandEventHandler(RadGridView_ItemCommand);
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the **createRadGrid()** either in the **page_init** or **page_load** event. if you are setting the event after, that could be the reason of it no firing.

Hope this is of any help.

Cheers.

Comment: Its very common when working with dynamic controls, the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx, helped me very much understanding what to do in what part of the page life cycle. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line:

```
PlaceHolder_RadGridView.Controls.Add(rg);
```

Right to after this line:

```
RadGrid rg = new RadGrid();
rg.ID = "RadGridView";
```

And see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay just tried this and nothing changed/happened, thanks for the response though

Comment: OK, where are you calling createRadGrid() then?  In what event?  It should be PreInit or Init.

Comment: I was running it in the Page_load() event in the (!Page.IsPostBack), but now i'm trying it outside of this statement.

Comment: Yes you have to recreate it on every page load, and you have to create in Init or PreInit,because viewstate loads after init, so viewstate wouldn't be restored from the grid.